# Como agregar paginacion a una tabla que carga con peticion AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Tengo un problema con una tabla que muestro en HTML pero cargo sus datos con una petición AJAX y le estoy intentando agregar una paginacion a dicha tabla, para la paginacion estoy intentando usar **DataTables**, el problema es que si agrego la funcion de DataTables para mostrar paginacion apesar de que la tabla si contiene un td me dice que no estoy mostrando ningun row y aparte cuando selecciono algún filtro en la tabla el contenido desaparece, no se como pueda configurar mi tabla para agregar una paginacion.

Este es el cuerpo HTML donde tengo mi tabla:

```html
<div class="tabla_ingresos">
   <table class="table_ingresos display" id="table_ingresos">
     <thead>
       <th>#</th>
       <th>Fecha de aportación</th>
       <th>No. Recibo</th>
       <th>Estatus</th>
       <th>Empresa</th>
       <th>Concepto</th>
       <th>Periodo</th>
       <th>Asesores</th>
       <th>Liberado</th>
       <th>Total</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
                        
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Y este es el codigo JavaScript que hace la peteicion a mi base de datos y el resultado lo mando al  de mi tabla haciendo uso de esta linea de código: **$("#table_ingresos tbody").html(data);**

```js
function listaIngresosGeneral(){
    
    let table_lista_ingresos = document.getElementById('table_ingresos');
    if(table_lista_ingresos){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "controladores/ControladorIngresos.php",
            data: {action: "consultaGeneralIngresos"},
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                $("#table_ingresos tbody").html(data);                
            }
        });
        $('#table_ingresos').DataTable();
    }
}
```

Y haciendo uso de esta linea: **$('#table_ingresos').DataTable();** le agrego la paginacion que me da DataTables y mi tabla se ve de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el primer problema es que apesar de que mi tabla ya tiene un  me sigue mostrando 0 entradas en la tabla y si selecciono algun filtro de los titulos de mi columna mi contenido desaparece.

La peticion AJAX se carga desde un archivo PHP, este es el código donde hago la consulta y luego recorro la respuesta de mi consulta a MySQL con un foreach he imprimo los resultados con un **echo**:

```
echo "<tr class='row'>";
            echo "<td><strong>".$id_ingresoM."</strong></td>";
            echo "<td>".$fecha_aportacion."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$no_recibo."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$estatusTexto."</td>";
            echo "<td><p style='font-size:13px;'><strong>".$empresaTexto."</strong></p></td>";
            echo "<td>".$conceptoTexto."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$periodo."</td>";
            if($cadenaDistribucion != ""){
                echo "<td>".$cadenaDistribucion."</td>";
            }else{
                echo "<td><span style='color:#d61313;'>Sin distribución</span></td>";
            }            
            echo "<td>".$liberado."</td>";
            echo "<td>"."$".number_format($total, 2)."</td>";
            echo "<td>
                    <form action='detallesIngreso' method='POST'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='ingresoEdit' id='ingresoEdit' value='".$id_ingresoM."'>
                        <input type='submit' data-id='".$id_ingresoM."' name='btnModificar".$incremento."' id='btnModificar".$incremento."' class='positiveButtonTable' value='Ver'>
                    </form>
                 </td>";
            echo "<td>
                    <input type='submit' onclick='eliminarRegistroIngreso(this.id);' data-id='".$id_ingresoM."' name='btnDelete".$incremento."' id='btnDelete".$incremento."' class='negativeButtonTable' value='Eliminar'>
                 </td>";
            echo "</tr>";
```

El problema es que no se si es correcto mostrar los resultados en la tabla de esta manera y como puedo agregar una paginacion a la tabla.

Comment: Estás creando la tabla antes de que se resuelva la petición AJAX y, por lo tanto, está vacía. Mueve esta línea `$('#table_ingresos').DataTable();` debajo de donde asignas el HTML, con eso debería funcionar.

Comment: Aparte, creo que es mala práctica enviar contenido HTML en una petición AJAX, porque puedes devolver solo un objeto JSON y dejar que _DataTables_ genere el HTML. Para "celdas especiales" puedes crear el formato declarando tus funciones [render()](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers#Functions)

Comment: @Triby ya intente colocando la linea de DateTable donde asigno el HTML pero ahora me da un error que no entiendo, este es el error: Uncaught TypeError: aa is undefined

Comment: @Triby ya lo logre, estaba enviando mal data, no tenia que imprimirlo con echo mas bien devolver el json de mi respuesta de la base de datos y darle formato.